# How do you turn a "for" into an async mode?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

```
export function RecommendList(data) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        let db = loadFB().firestore();
        let query = db.collection('users').where("recommend", ">", "0").orderBy("recommend", "asc")
        let user_list = []; 
        let uid_arr=[];
        let result = [];
        query.get().then(async docs => {
            docs.forEach(doc => {
                const recommender = doc.data();
                const recommend_id = recommender.recommend;
                const recommend_person = recommender.displayName;                                
                user_list.push({id : recommend_id, recommend_person : recommend_person });
            })        

            uid_arr = getRecommendList(user_list);

            console.log("getRecommendList",uid_arr);

            for(let i = 0; i < uid_arr.length; i++) {
                const user_doc = await db.collection('users').doc(uid_arr[i].id).get();
                console.log(user_doc.data());
                let user_info = user_doc.data()
                user_info.betball_dupli_count = uid_arr[i].count;
                user_info.recommend_person = uid_arr[i].person;
                console.log('displayname' , user_info.displayName , 'betball count',user_info.betball_dupli_count,'person',user_info.recommend_person);
                result.push(user_info);
            } 
            console.log('result!', result);
            dispatch({
                type: types.SET_USER_LIST,
                data: result,
                page: 1
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I work on importing data from the Fire Store and sending it to the dispatch.
By the way, I want to make a code that increases the efficiency of this work by asynchronous mode in javascript. I'd like to know how to wait and process a form asynchronously.

In short, how to turn "for" of this code into async mode!

Comment: wrap it into an async method that returns what you want to return.

Comment: I would say create a new async function, put the loop into it, and await that in the place you're doing the for loop

Comment: https://www.taniarascia.com/promise-all-with-async-await/

Comment: Very worth reading [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With minimal changes to your existing code:

```js
let userQueries = [];
for (let i = 0; i < uid_arr.length; i++) {
    userQueries.push(
        db.collection('users').doc(uid_arr[i].id).get()
        .then(user_doc => {
            console.log(user_doc.data());
            let user_info = user_doc.data()
            user_info.betball_dupli_count = uid_arr[i].count;
            user_info.recommend_person = uid_arr[i].person;
            console.log('displayname', user_info.displayName, 'betball count', user_info.betball_dupli_count, 'person', user_info.recommend_person);
            result.push(user_info);

        })
    )
}
await Promise.all(userQueries);
```

The outer `for` loop will just initiate the queries and the `then` part of each one will run when the specific query is complete. Outside of the `for` loop, the `Promise.all` call will wait for all of the queries to complete before continuing.